# Trying to append link/href path to original code

Tags: jquery, if-statement, href

I am loading content from a different page of my site into a result-container (div class).

```
    $('.result-container').load('../path/otherpage.html #ID');
```

So far so good, that works.
Now, I need to update any link within the result-container when it s clicked. Reason being, they all links still point to their original location (from where they were loaded from).

The idea is , when clicking on a link, I get the href attribute. If it starts with "files/", than it is a link relative to the original page (if it starts with something else, it is a link to somewhere else and is ok). So, I need to add to the front of the (just clicked) href "../path/", to make the final href path look like "../path/files/etc....".
I have some bits working, but really struggle to piece it all together.... can anyone reach me a hand please?
Thanks!
M.

```
    $(function() {
    $(".result-container").live("click",   //on click on element
                     function() {
                     $.get($(this).attr("href"), //get the href attribute                                              
                              if ($('a[href^="files/"]'))   //if attribute starts with "files/"
                                 {function() {
                                 var href = $(this).attr('href'); //get the attribute content - guess I could have done that above?
                                 $(this).attr('href', '../start/path/' + href); //append the start path to original path
                                             };
                                 }
                           )};
                           )};
```

---

Excellent, Thank you !!!!!
Now I am loading an element from a different page on my site with:

```
$('.result-container').load(../path/conetent.html #unique-ID); //load conent from different page on my site
```

on click, it changes every element which starts with "files/" to "../path/files/":

```
  $(function() {
    $(".result-container").live("click",
                     function() {
                        $('.result-container').html();
                        var test = $('.result-container').html().replace(/"files\//gi, '"../path/files/');
                        $('.result-container').html(test);                       
                           }); });
```

That works. This changes the original content and displays the altered content after an active click in the .result-container. 
Now I am trying to remove the .live("click", trigger here. (This trigger is only there, because my initial approach to achieve this was different). But when I remove the "click", this script does not change the text automatically... Any idea on how this executes and displays the altered content after I load the content from the unique ID container?

Comment: clicking on a link, I get the href attribute... Are you modifying the attribute of a link within the .result-container? If so your selector is a bit wrong... `$('.result-container').live('click', function(){ $('. result-container a[href^="files"]').each( )`... is a more appropriate selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just replacing any instance of the string "files/ with "/path/. So something like

```
var new_text = $('#my_div').html().replace(/"files\//gi, '"/path/');
$('#my_div').html(new_text);
```

You'll have to forgive me if my regex is a bit off but that should give you an idea.

Comment: Thank you very much !!! got this to work (see my edited question). However, how can I achieve that this change is done automatically, after loading the content, and not just after me clicking? Any idea

Comment: How does this content get loaded? My guess is via an ajax call. If so you can just throw all of this into the success function of the call.

Comment: the content gets loaded with $(.target).load(path/path). I described the complete way how I do it now including your code in my post. And I am not able to get it into one singe function.... :( How sad !

Comment: Oh, sorry if that was already there and I missed it. The load() method let's you pass a callback function as a parameter. What you can then do is .load('path/path', function() { //add your stuff here });. You should be able to throw all of your replace code into this function and it won't get called until the load() finishes.

Comment: Man, I tried MANY things. Many. Really many. But not .load('path', funktion(){ //my stuff//}); etc...... Thank you very much!!!!! It is working. Syntax nightmare - I am having trouble with it.... One last question: what does the "\//gi" exactly mean? I know what the line of code does, but I am puzzled about the exact... well, Syntax...